# Magento PayPal checkout sales not showing in revenue

Tags: magento-1.9, payment

I have sales that have been completed in PayPal. However, when i look at the reports and the dashboard, all the PayPal sales don't account for the revenue and lifetime sales. Is there a way to fix this?